# How to hide a html helper using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 <tr id="status">
        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</td>           
    </tr>


<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    var StatusVal = $('input[name=Status]').val()

    if (!StatusVal) {
        $('#status').hide();
    }

});
```

I want to hide the status property of the model if its value is false.

Comment: I assume that the user can change the value of your property. If so, you need to add a listener on the `change` (or `click` if the property is a checkbox) event of the property.

Comment: No , user can only read it. write  will be done by admin .

Comment: The why not "hide" the entire row on the server side: `@if (model.Status == true) { <tr id="status"><td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</td></tr>}`. You only render the property if it is true.

Comment: I didn't know that we can use if condition using @ in mvc. Thanks a lot ! :-)

Comment: I ended up with these two lines.   @if (item.Status){<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</td> }
            @if(!item.Status){<td> <h5>Your account is still not verified by the admin</h5> </td>}

Comment: You can also use `else` instead of the second `@if`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `#status` it should be `#Status`

```
 if (StatusVal == false) {
    $('#Status').hide();
 }
```

Or directly use as

```
 if ($('input[id="Status"]').val() == false) {
    $('#Status').hide();
 }
```